# Pentaho Data Integration - Excel Writer Output File Size

Tags: excel, pentaho, etl, kettle, pentaho-spoon

#### Is PDI inefficient in terms of writing excel xlsx file with Microsoft Excel Writer.

A transformed excel data file in Pentaho output seems to be three times the size, if the data was transformed manually. Is this inefficiency expected or is there a workaround for it.

A CSV file of the same transformed output is way smaller in size. Have I configured something wrong ?

Comment: Can you please give specific examples? In my small test the xlsx file created with PDI was 40% of the size of a similar file created with Excel.

Comment: Well a recent test case, the CSV file output was 5.7Mb, however the Excel writer ouput xlsx file was 8.9Mb. Well normally a xlsx file must be considerably smaller than the csv file. Could there be any configuration we might have to check for Microsoft excel writer in Pentaho.

Comment: can you list the contents of the zip file, to list file sizes and compression?

Comment: Folders - docProps, xl, _rels. File [Content_Types.xml]. Well in the test you performed did your file end up being 40% greater size or lesser

Comment: Excel created a file that was 40% bigger than Pentaho.

Answer (score 1):

xlsx files should normally be smaller in size than CSV, since they consist of XML data compressed in ZIP files. Pentaho's `Microsoft Excel Writer` uses `org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFWorkbook` and `org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook` to write xlsx files, and they create compressed files so this should not be your issue.

To check the files you could check with a zip utility, to see the file sizes and compression rate, to see if there is a bug. You could also try to open the file in Excel and re-save it, to see if that gives a smaller size, which could indicate an inefficiency.

Comment: I opened and saved the file with excel and saved it, no luck.

Comment: What was the result?

Comment: The file size unfortunately didn't change at all. Thanks for the help though

Comment: The fact that the file size didn't change says that this works correctly from Kettle, and is no bug.